# Glide won't show image from localhost

Tags: android, android-glide

glide don't show any image from my localhost

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cont);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null);
    String uri = "https://192.168.43.9/uploads/184990624.jpg";
    ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    Hero hero = heroes.get(position);

    Glide.with(cont).load(uri).into(img);

    return view;
}}
```

Comment: is your device you are testing from capable of accessing this ip address?

Comment: @R.B are you testing on real device or in emulator ? please confirm

Answer (score 0):

With the use of  [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) you can get the public IP which should solve your issue.

Comment: It solves it only if the accessibility of the IP address is the cause.

Comment: I guess @R.B might be testing on real device not in emulator, in that case definitely localhost url will not work.

Comment: @Krishna Sharma.  Why?